# Convert MIPS32 to C: adding an array's base address to arbitrary value and its meaning

Tags: c, assembly, mips

I'm working on a homework assignment right now, and I'm given this information:

**$s6** is the location of the base address of array **A**, **$s0** is the location of the value of **f** (not specified).

It wants me to convert some instructions to a C statement. Here is my question though, because if this is answered I can very easily do the rest of this problem:

add $t0, $s6, $s0

Is that saying `$t0 = (the base address of array A) + f`
or is it saying `$t0 = A[0+f]` ?

Because if the base address of A were 0x04000000 and I used addi to add 4 to that base address, yielding 0x04000004, and assigning that value to t0, what I'm saying is that t0 = A[1] (assuming I'm storing integers).

But since I don't know the value of f, I'm unsure of how to represent this in C, because I know I'm modifying the index, but I don't know by how much. Would it be more accurate to say (given the instruction above):

```
$t0 = A[f/4]
```

I'm new to all of this ha. Hopefully I demonstrated that I've done a bit of research trying to figure this out.

Thanks

OSFTW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no dereferencing in this instruction:

```
add $t0, $s6, $s0
```

It's like saying

```
t0 = s6 + s0;
```

In a C-like pseudocode.  Or for your example:

```
t0 = (char *)A + f;
```

To get a value out of A, it would look something like:

```
lw $t1, 0($t0)
```

After having done the previous `add` instruction so that `$t0` points to the right place in the array.

Comment: Oh, so it's kind of like casting? Because at s6 there is nothing but a memory address, correct? So we're casting that as (in this scenario) an int?

Comment: Casting only means something if you have types, and assembly language doesn't.  I'm not sure exactly what you're getting at.

Comment: Here's where my confusion lies:
We're adding an address to some obscure integer. The result is meaningless unless placed in the context of that array,and unless that integer is divisible by four (in the case of an array of integers). 

To help clarify, what the problem later does is the following:
`lw $s0,0($t0)`
So it's now treating t0 as an array, trying to access it from it's base address. And, assuming that f was divisible by 4 and positive, all that is doing is referencing an element of the array at some incremented index, just in a different manner,correct? Something like:
`s0 = A[f/4]`

Comment: Ok great. So the following lines of code basically mean `f = A[f/4]` ?:
`add $t0, $s6, $s0` `lw $s0,0($t0)`

Comment: Assuming `f` is in `s0`, and a pointer to the first element of `A` is in `s6` (as described in your question), yes.  And that `A` is an array of 4-byte objects.

Comment: That answers my question perfectly, thank you! Sorry it took me a bit to describe the crux of my issue, but I appreciate your time and effort.